# Program aborted after use tf.io.gfile.makedirs

Tags: python, tensorflow, hadoop, hdfs

- pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
- TensorFlow version: 1.14.0
- Python version: 3.6.8
- Hadoop version: Hadoop trunk (hadoop-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT)

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
Release:    7.6.1810
Codename:   Core
```

I follow this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/hadoop.md) to set up Hadoop environment 
After execute below snippet of code, there is no any output, and my terminal freezing up

**Code to reproduce the issue**

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.io.gfile.makedirs("hdfs://kevin0:8020/user/root/test")
```

What else I need to setup?

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here even though it is present in Github, for the benefit of the Stackoverflow Community.

`Program aborted after use tf.io.gfile.makedirs` issue was because of Hadoop compile from source code that don't have `libhdfs` in lib/native.

It was resolved after downloading Hadoop-3.2.1.

For more details please refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34704)